# transitive subgroups of $S_n$

Tags: gr.group-theory

For a subset $X$ of $S_n$ (the symmetric group of degree $n$) define $C(X)$ to be the union of all conjugates of elements of $X.$

**Question 1** What is that called?

**Question 2** Over all transitive subgroups $H$ of $S_n,$ which one has the *smallest* $C(H)?$

Comment: Question 2 clear when $n$ is prime (minimum is for $H$ cyclic of order $p$,  and then $C(H)$ has cardinal $(n-1)!+1$). For other small values of $n$ it  should be easy to check.

Comment: For Question 1, this is quite close to the normal closure (or conjugate closure), but not exactly. (Usually, one considers the subgroup generated by this set.)

Comment: @verret I *did* know that. The difference is precisely what makes the question interesting.

Comment: @verret Otherwise, the closure will always be $S_n$ or $A_n.$

Comment: Q1: invariant subset.

https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Invariant_subset

Comment: Well, it doesn't seem a very natural thing to consider to me. Anyway, YCor gave the answer for $n$ prime. For $n\in\{4,6,8,9,10\}$ the minimum is always achieved by a regular group, namely $C_2^2,D_6,C_2^3,C_3^2,D_{10}$. In a way, not so surprising, as you want a group representing very few cycle types.

Comment: @verret Thank you for your opinion on the naturality of the question. This concept does actually come up. A lot.

Comment: @IgorRivin  Ok. For $n=15$, minimality is not achieved by the (unique, up to conjugacy) regular group, but by $A_5$ acting on $15$ points. The list of minimal examples looks very irregular to me. I would be surprised if one could determine it in general.

Comment: @verret I am not sure. For $n=2^k$ it should be easy (and for primes it is easy). In between, it might be hard.

Comment: In fact, I think any prime power is easy: if $n$ is a power of a prime $p$, then a Sylow $p$-subgroup $P$ of $G$ is transitive, and an element of order $p$ in the center of $P$ will be fixed-point-free, so we always have that class, and so the elementary abelian regular example is minimal.

Comment: For question 2: if $X$ is taken as a cyclic subgroup of order $n$ in $S_n$, then all elements of $C(X)$ can have orders only among the divisors of $n$; as this seems restrictive considering the possibilities for order of a general element of $S_n$, this could be a candidate. I do not have anything more rigorous to justify.

Comment: @PVanchinathan It looks like this this is never the right candidate, unless $n$ is prime. There are a few reasons for this. One is that the conjugacy class of elements $n$-cycles is very large. The other is that you can often represent a proper subset of the classes represented by this group. Indeed, if there is a non-cyclic group of order $n$, then that group in its regular action will necessarily beat the cyclic group of order $n$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since nothing else came up, I'm posting this as an answer.

For $n$ a power of a prime $p$, the answer is any group of exponent $p$, acting regularly.

Indeed, if $n$ is a power of $p$, then a Sylow $p$-subgroup $P$ of $H$ is transitive, and any element of order $p$ in the center of $P$ will be fixed-point-free, so $H$ always contains an element of cycle type $(p,\ldots,p)$. In a group of exponent $p$ acting regularly, every non-trivial element has this cycle type, so this is best possible.

For other small values of $n$, I obtained the following answers computationally:

- $n=6$ : dihedral group, acting regularly.
- $n=10$ : dihedral group, acting regularly.
- $n=12$ : $A_4$, acting regularly.
- $n=14$ : dihedral group, acting regularly (edging out by less than 0.1% a group isomorphic to $AGL(1,8)$).
- $n=15$ : $A_5$, acting on the cosets of a Sylow $2$-subgroup.
- $n=18$ : generalised dihedral group over an elementary abelian group, acting regularly.
- $n=20$ : a group of the form $C_2^4:C_5$ (edging out another group by about 0.01%).

I'm not sure why there are so many extremely close calls. I'm guessing it has to do with the wide range of size of conjugacy classes in $S_n$ (so two groups might contain the same large classes, but differ in some small classes).

Perhaps some other cases can be done, like $n$ twice a prime but, to me, the general problem seems hard, even intractable.